# JSON Response not parsing, using Wordpress and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I have a front end editor set up using AJAX to edit posts in Wordpress. Everything was going good, my form submits to a php file which successully updates the database and then uses the following function to create a response:

```
  function generate_response($action, $message = '', $details = '' ){
    $response = array(
        "action"  => $action,
        "message" => $message,
        "details" => $details
        );

    echo json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
```

However, the response does not appear to be encoded properly, When I log my `jsonResponse` return in JS I'm getting this:

```
Object {action: "updated", message: "Succes (no changes detected).", details: ""}
```

Which I'm pretty sure is malforemd JSON because `action`, `message`, and `details` are not double-quoted, right?

I try to parse the response and all I get is `null`:

```
  response = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonResponse);
  console.log(response); //returns null
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I correct and the response is not fomratted properly and if so, how would I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log the result from ajax, you get:

```
Object {action: "updated", message: "Succes (no changes detected).", details: ""}
```

That's already an object, not a JSON string, which means you probably set `dataType: 'JSON'` in your ajax call, and JSON is parsed automagically by jQuery, parsing it again just causes errors.

All you need to do is use response, no parsing needed :

```
var action = response.action;
```

Comment: I ran into some different issues which I'll have to figure out before I can know if you're answer was right, although I'm pretty sure it is.

Answer (score 0):

@adeneo So when I am running a query to load top 5 posts and then whaterver results I am getting they would be encoded to json.The output I am getting would be a object and not a JSON string right?

Yesterday spent few hours doing stringify- just to convert it to json assuming myoutput was a json string.

Comment: If whatever is returned from the server is properly encoded, like with json_encode, and dataType is set to JSON in jQuery's ajax function, the result will be a javascript object ready for use, as jQuery does the JSON.parse part internally for you.